# Redirect if access page without passing through another

Tags: javascript, html

For example I got 3 pages:

```
page1.html
page2.html
page3.html
```

How can I block people from accessing `page2` without going to `page1` first?
I'd like the only way to access this page it'd be by passing to `page1` and clicking a link. Then from `page2`, I can access `page3`. Thanks!
If someone tries to access it, either an error or a redirect to `page1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies to do this. I'm not the best at javascript, but here is what I found that you can modify.

So here is a step by step process you can use to get your result. This example came from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

1. You need to set a cookie on page1.html.

```js
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

2. Now you need to get and check the cookies.

```js
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user=getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
       user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
           setCookie("username", user, 30);
       }
    }
}
```

Hopefully, this will help you. Here is a fiddle with the complete JS: https://jsfiddle.net/uv3joc2b/

Comment: im really bad at this sort of stuff, so I copy the first code in page1, then the second code on page2? How will it know that the user didnt go from page1 to page3?

Comment: KidsPersonalTv,That is correct. The second code goes on the page you are checking for the cookie, so page 1 and 3. If you need to, put both pieces of the code on all pages so page2 cookie gets read by the page3 cookie. Im not that knowledgeable at js cookies, but that is what I found on the internet...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using static html pages, you can add a cookie in page1.html, then read the cookie in page2.html.
If it doesn't exist redirect the user to page1.html